# Azure/IntelliJ shows runScenario instead of actual test name using Cucumber

Tags: java, azure, cucumber

I have just added my cucumber test to an Azure pipeline. After running the pipeline I noticed that my cucumber tests are showing up as `runScenario` instead of the test name.
[image: Example of my pipeline run - Failed tests]
If I click on the `runScenario` and I go to Attachments I do see that it shows my test scenario there.

If I run it in IntelliJ my tests shows up as `runScenario []`

[image: IntelliJ]

I've googled a bit but cant seem to find how to fix that. Any idea how to show my test scenario or Feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Agent job tasks I used Maven.
In the configuration under `JUnit Test Results` add the path to your Junit result (Should be an .xml file). For me specifically it was under:

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/<project>/target/cucumber-junitReports/Cucumber.xml`